# buscar dados em tabela MySQL e php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho a tabela A com os campos id e usuario
e tabela B com id, dados e id_A;
Na página PHP eu quero q apareça o conteudo da tabela B, e com o id_A buscar o nome na tabela A.
O pricipal para mim seria a busca de uma tabela em outra mesmo, pois o conteudo ja consigo mandar para a página.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que relacionar as tabelas no select, tenta assim:

```
SELECT b.id, b.dados FROM tablela a, tabelab b WHERE a.id = b.id
```